# How to combine a constant string to all values of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this:

```
$arr = array(
    "0" => "Jack",
    "1" => "Peter",
    "2" => "ali"
);
```

Now I want to add `My name is:` to the first of all those values...! How can I do that?

**Note:** I can do that using a loop, and fetch all values, and combine them using `.` and push them into array again. But I want to know is there any function for doing that? Or any better solution?

So I want this output:

```
$newarr = array(
    "0" => "My name is: Jack",
    "1" => "My name is: Peter",
    "2" => "My name is: ali"
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array_walk` as below :

```
<?php 

$arr = array (
        "0" => "Jack",
        "2" => "Peter",
        "3" => "ali"
);

array_walk($arr, function(&$item) {
    $item = 'My Name is : '.$item;
});

print_r($arr);
?>
```

or you can use `array_map` as below

```
<?php 
$arr = array (
        "0" => "Jack",
        "2" => "Peter",
        "3" => "ali"
);

$arr = array_map(function($val) {
    return "My name is : ".$val;
} , $arr);

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Or [array_map](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php) if you don't want the original array to be altered.

Answer (score 3):

Use **array_walk**. It Applies a user supplied function to every member of an array. In your case, we are going to concatenate your string. See the example below.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "0" => "Jack",
    "2" => "Peter",
    "3" => "ali"
);

array_walk($arr, function(&$name) {
    $name = 'My Name is : ' . $name;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use array_map function, see code

```
$arr = array (
           "0" => "Jack",
           "2" => "Peter",
           "3" => "ali"
              );

function changeName($name)
{
    return('My name is: '.$name);
}


$b = array_map("changeName", $arr);
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to only output the "My name is:" when needed.  You may use **array_map** or a **foreach** loop.

If you keep the array with only names you can reuse it more easily in the future.

Consider the following cases:

- sorting the names
- providing a different string for the same array later in the code
- using the names without the string later in the code

Also, you don't have to explicitly set the keys in this case, you could use notation like this:

```
$names = [ "Jim", "Dave"];
```

Comment: Well, actually I can't fit your solution with my question .., May you please implement your solution based that array in my question?

Comment: My answer builds on the others by suggesting how to use the code they provided. The key is that you shouldn't modify the array values, just add the string when needed.

Comment: Ah I see what your point ..! But actually your solution isn't proper for me *(according to reality)*. But ok thanks, +1 for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop which uses the original array elements:

```
$arr = array (
           "0" => "Jack",
           "1" => "Peter",
           "2" => "ali"
              );
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    $arr[$i] = "My name is: " . $arr[$i];
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks .....! +1 *(However I mentioned in the question as a **note** that I don't want your algorithm)*

Comment: @stack Right you are, missed that. Then take the `array_walk` approach though simply looping over it may actually be the *fastest* approach (no need to call a function everytime).